# The application is installed but not running or visible on virtual device

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

```
[2013-05-17 03:56:29 - beginner] Android Launch!
[2013-05-17 03:56:29 - beginner] adb is running normally.
[2013-05-17 03:56:29 - beginner] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-05-17 03:56:29 - beginner] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-05-17 03:56:29 - beginner] Performing sync
[2013-05-17 03:56:29 - beginner] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'wlah'
[2013-05-17 03:56:30 - beginner] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2013-05-17 03:56:30 - beginner] \beginner\bin\beginner.apk installed on device
[2013-05-17 03:56:30 - beginner] Done!
```

I don't know why this is happening. The AVD was running my apps a few days ago. But now it's just displaying this message on the Console but the application is not actually installed in the AVD (or the emulator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application installed but you didn't mention the launcher activity
**Modify Your Manifest File :-**

```
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity android:name=".YourActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
    </application>
```

**Update:**

> This :

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASHACTIVITY" />
```

> To:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Comment: thanks for replying...but i had already set it as <category Android:name= "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">

Comment: and it is not even installed or visible on my virtual device

Answer (score 2):

This might be hint: No Launcher activity found!

It says you don't have set launcher activity on your application's AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.prajwaljpj.beginner.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASHACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: <category Android:name= "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"> this is already set...still not woring

Comment: what is SPLASHACTIVITY in <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASHACTIVITY" />..see my edit